# Google Analytics Event [Form Submission] overfiring compared to actuals

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm running into an issue for a form submission event firing too often (200x). The trigger for the event is created from the GTM standard Trigger Type of "Form Submission" where we're checking validation and have specified the conditions to be only on the Page URL where the form exists. We've tested it in GTM preview mode and seeing that the event fires.

Update 1/28-

The form is on a pop-up through our homepage (https://mybrightwheel.com) after the user clicks on "Request a Demo" (so the event fire should not happen on this initial button click). The event fire should occur after they get into the demo request form and complete a successful form submit. And below that is a shot of the trigger. Any help here is appreciated.

[image: Homepage where form in question resides]

[image]

[image: Here's what the trigger looks like in GA]

Comment: The form doesn't actually work?

Comment: Yes, the form captures successful submits. Can confirm through test submits.

Answer (score 0):

That trigger hasn't specified which button it's firing on. You have 2 buttons in that screenshot, it's recording both. You need to tell it to fire on one button or the other by specifying link text or link url (i.e. where the user ends up on clicking the link)

Comment: Hey, great point and you are correct. I just updated my question to be more specific (sorry!). Ultimately, we're not tracking the initial click of "Request a demo" click that serves the pop-up, we're looking to fire the event upon a successful form submission, or at the least one the "Schedule Demo" button instead. I've added the new screenshot above. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: So, you've now got 3 buttons in that screenshot. If the only way you're defining where it should fire is by that one url, and then telling it to fire on all forms, it's going to fire on all forms on that url.